# What is the fastest way to display an image in QT on X11 without OpenGL?

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, x11, xlib

I need to display a raw image in a QT widget. I'm running X11 on a framebuffer, so OpenGL is not available.

Both the image and the framebuffer are in the same format - RGB565, but I can change it to any other format if needed. I don't need blending or scaling. I just need to display pixels as is.

I'm using QPainter::drawImage, but it converts QImage to QPixmap and this conversion seems to be very slow. Also it is backed by Xrender and I think there is unnecessary overhead required to support blending in Xrender which I don't really need

Is there any better way? If it is not available in QT, I can use Xlib or any other library or protocol. I can modify the driver, X server or anything else.

Comment: I'd suggest looking in the Graphics Dojo blog series: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/category/graphics-dojo/ - Some of the newer posts are specifically on graphics performance. It's a great resource, and worth skimming through the older posts too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to use [XPutImage](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XPutImage.html)? (or [XShmPutImage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xshmputimage) if you going to transfer image more then once from client and have MIT-SHM extension available) Also look at [video4linux webcam sample viewer.c](http://alumnos.elo.utfsm.cl/~yanez/video-for-linux-2-sample-programs/), but they convert 565 to 16 or 24 bit depth before sending. For your setup it should be possible to send image without conversion

Comment: Yes, I have switched to the "raster" QT graphic engine, which is using MIT-SHM under the hood and converts my drawImage to XShmPutImage. It gave me significant performance gains, but now I'm wondering if I can do even better than that

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth setting the `QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM` environment variable. I was having issues with the X11 renderer becoming very, very slow. On setting `QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM = 'raster'`, the QT rendering bypasses the X11 rendering engine, which can (as in my experience) be significantly more efficient. Other valid values for `QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM` are `'native'` and `'opengl'`, but `'raster'` worked for me. I'll be interested to see how you got on.